# Changing property of an object and Tree update

Tags: apache-flex, tree

I have an ArrayCollection which is a dataProvider for a Tree component. 
Objects inside ArrayCollection have _selected property.
After setting object's _selected property to true the Tree component should get updated (specific row should get highlighted). How could I achieve this? Do I have to write an ItemRenderer?

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to write an itemRenderer. To set the highlight, the Tree component's selected property must point to the object in the ArrayCollection that has been selected. Whether you want to listen for a change to the object's _selected property or add it in when you set _selected is up to you.

I'm kind of in a rush right now, will add more to this later if you need.